# Subsetting from a Data Frame

Tags: r

I'm early in the process of learning R. Say I have a data frame with a column named "Gender". If I want to retrieve all rows where Gender is "female" there are at least two ways I can do this:

```
FemaleSmokers <- df[df$Gender=="female", , drop = FALSE]
FemaleSmokers <- subset(df, Gender=="female")
```

1) Is there a best practice on when to use one over the other?
2) In the first approach, why do I need to preface the column with the name of the data frame when R should know which data frame I working with.

Comment: Welcome to R, May be this answer here gives you some insight about your Q.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Comment: On the help page for [`?subset`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/subset), you'll see this under the "Warning" section: "This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences."

Comment: @user5249203 - Your link helps with my first question, but not the second.

Comment: Other alternative would be dplyr: `FemaleSmokers <- df %>% dplyr::filter(Gender == "female")`

Comment: @user5249203 - That doesn't really answer my question. Yes I know I'm indexing the column. But why do I need to specify the name of the data frame when R should know what the name of the data fram already is, since I'm indexing against it.

Comment: @RandyMinder, I think the reason is that you can index by anything you want, not neccesary against the `df`, you could do for example (A dummy one) `df[1==1]`.

Comment: You need to specify the data.frame because you don't get any special evaluation within `[]`; it just takes index values, Booleans, or row/column names as strings. It doesn't operate on string names until everything is reduced to a single value, which it _then_ uses as a lookup value. That's actually good, as it lets you easily operate on those values.

Comment: This side gives different possibilities to subset a data frame. https://www.r-bloggers.com/5-ways-to-subset-a-data-frame-in-r/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this worked out example will help you

```
df<-data.frame( Name = c("mark", "joe", "cathy","zoya"), 
               Gender = c("Male","Male","Female", "Female"))
  Name Gender
1  mark   Male
2   joe   Male
3 cathy Female
4  zoya Female

subsetting of a dataframe (df) is done by 
df[row,column] 
For example, df[1:2,1:2]
 Name Gender
1 mark   Male
2  joe   Male

In your case, we are evaluating a condition on the dataframe
# both are valid
df[df$Gender == "Female",] or  df[df[,2] == "Female",]
```

which is nothing but indexing the df as

```
df[c(3,4),] or df[c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE),]
df$Gender == "Female"
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

`df[c(3,4),]` Which basically rows 3 and 4, and all columns 
So, you are basically extracting variables to pass them as index. To extract variables of specific column from a data frame we use $ on dataframe help("$") help("[").

one more useful resource http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/subsetting.htm

Rethinking about your Q, Why to preface the Column with df when R needs to know the df you are working with ! I could not have a better explanation than above, You need to extract the variable to pass row indexes where your condition has been evaluated `TRUE`. Probably in dataframe columns are not referred as variables.

But, I have a good news, where things work like you think. Where, columns are referred to as variables. It is `datatable`. Where columns are referred as variables, thus making easy to understand syntax for indexing, joining and other data manipulations. It is an amazing package, and easy to master it.

```
require(data.table)
DT<-data.table(df)
 Name Gender
1:  mark   Male
2:   joe   Male
3: cathy Female
4:  zoya Female

DT[Gender == "Female"]
    Name Gender
1: cathy Female
2:  zoya Female
```

Yes, you don't need to preface the df again, just passing columns. Best part is, it is more efficient, faster and easier to use compared to data.frame
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `filter` function from `dplyr` library?

```
FemaleSmokers <- filter(df, Gender=="female")
```